# Parse.com javascript update not working

Tags: jquery, parse-platform

```
    $("#logot_name").click(function(){

    var current_user="pranav";
    alert(current_user);//alert works

    var Login = Parse.Object.extend("Login");
    var query = new Parse.Query("Login");
    query.equalTo("username",current_user);
    query.descending("logintime");
    query.first({
      success: function(object) {
      alert(123);//no alert

        var d=$.now();
        object.set("logouttime",d);
        object.save();

      },
      error: function(object, error) {
      alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);//no error
      }
    });

alert(1234);//alert works
    Parse.User.logOut();
    $.session.set("Name"," ")
    $.session.set("id"," ")
    window.location.replace("index.html");  


    });
```

the above update object statement doesnt work. i have put it in document.ready,also the user logs out successfully.but the query doesnt execute also no error msg is displayed. somehow the query stmt is ignored.why?

Comment: Have you added the reference to the Parse library JS file, and called `Parse.initialize()` with your account keys before running this script?

Comment: yeah other queryies on same page are working

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove quote to refer to your var:

Replace

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Login");
```

By

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Login);
```

Comment: Needs to be

var Login = Parse.Object.extend("Login");

var query = new Parse.Query(Login);